# How to get user's id from response json

Tags: java, json, spring, mockmvc

I have mockmvc test.

```
@Test
    public void findAllUsers() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("http://localhost:8081/user/get")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", is("Ann")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].products", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].name", is("John")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].products", hasSize(1)));
    }
```

How can I get user id from this response to some additional variable?

For example I want something like this:

```
String id = jsonPath"$[0].id";
```

I know that it will not work, but I need to have user's id in variable.

Comment: can you show your JSON output?

Comment: @Deadpool, this is a part of JSON
{
        "id": "e7485042-b46b-11e9-986a-b74e614de0b0",
        "name": "Ann",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": "f3a8af30-b46b-11e9-95e5-17389c833c62",
                "name": "product2"
            },
            {
                "id": "f3a775de-b46b-11e9-95e4-af440b6044d4",
                "name": "product1"
            }
        ]
    }

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the result of you get call using `andReturn()` method. Then you can read the response content, read and assign your id to a variable. Please try :

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("http://localhost:8081/user/get")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", is("Ann")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].products", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].name", is("John")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].products", hasSize(1)))
                .andReturn();
String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
String id = JsonPath.read(content, "[0].id");
```

Comment: Happy it helped!

Answer (score 0):

`$.id` will work to get id or to get user`s id `$.*.id` or `$[*].id` will work.

[JsonPath online](https://jsonpath.com/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I need to get id while executing test
I can't get it just using this `$.id`